# is there a way to convert a dense optical flow to sparse optical flow in opencv c++?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opticalflow

```
    Mat i1 = imread("1.jpg", 0); //read as a gray scale image
    Mat i2 = imread("2.jpg", 0); //reas as a gray scale image

    Mat flowMat; 

    vector <Point2f> i1_corner, i2_corner;
    vector <uchar> status;
    vector <float> err;

    goodFeaturesToTrack(i1, i1_corner, 1000, 0.01, 30);
    calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(i1, i2, i1_corner, i2_corner, status, err);
```

I want to track the **i1_corner** feature points in **i2** image

in the above code I am tracking them using the  iterative Lucas-Kanade method

```
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(i1, i2, i1_corner, i2_corner, status, err);
```

But can I track them using the DIS optical flow which is implemeted in the following function in opencv

```
createOptFlow_DIS(DISOpticalFlow::PRESET_ULTRAFAST)->calc(i1, i2, flowMat);
```

the above function finds the dense optical flow for every pixel in image **i1**

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the optical flow (displacement) vector of the respective position in the flow field:

```
Mat i1 = imread("1.jpg", 0); //read as a gray scale image
Mat i2 = imread("2.jpg", 0); //reas as a gray scale image

Mat flowMat; 

vector <Point2f> i1_corner, i2_corner;
vector <uchar> status;
vector <float> err;

goodFeaturesToTrack(i1, i1_corner, 1000, 0.01, 30);
createOptFlow_DIS(DISOpticalFlow::PRESET_ULTRAFAST)->calc(i1, i2, flowMat);
i2_corner.resize(i1_corner.size());
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < i1_corner.size(); i++)
{
    i2_corner[i] = i1_corner[i] + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(i1_corner[i]);
}
```

Please note, that the last line reads the flow at the pixel postion, i.e. i1_corner position are rounded. To get the flow value on a subpixel level you will need to perform an interpolation there. However, since in particular the DIS flow computes very blurry (rough) flow fields, interpolation will not change the tracking significantly.